# Recipe organizer for Windows with attractive GUI

Tags: windows

Does anybody know a recipe manager for Windows 7 with a nice-looking GUI. I already peaked at [BigOven](http://www.bigoven.com/recipe-software.aspx) and [Rezkonv](http://www.rezkonv.de/) and the feature list is really impressive. Nevertheless the GUI of these recipe managers seems terrible to me compared to Mac solutions like [MacGourmet](http://www.macgourmet.com/).

Does anybody know a Windows recipe manager with an acceptable GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Hrm, depending on which features you want you could take a look at [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) and adapt that to your needs. The crosslinking could come in rather handy when referencing sauces or small things with separate recipes into bigger recipes, right?

I use that Wiki to organize my Cocktail-Recipes, and it has been working well for years.

Comment: There ought to be a standard HTML microformat for recipes, to make it easier to cut, paste and exchange recipes, but I'm dreaming...